# Combine ASP.NET WebForms with DotVVM in single project

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotvvm

currently I have the web application using Web.Forms. It consist of more than thousand pages and rewriting everything from scratch will be extremely time consuming. 
I'm planning to gradually rewrite each page while the others remains as webforms.

Is that even possible? Having mix of DotVVM and Web.Forms pages within single project?

What would you suggest to start with? Ideally I'd like users not to even know that the page looks different. I don't care about URLs as it's admin application.

From what I learned so far I need to duplicate my current MasterPage to the .dotmaster page and then add views for pages I am rewriting.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: _"Best way"_ is _subject to opinion_ sadly and therefore off-topic on SO.  [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a [sample app](https://github.com/riganti/dotvvm-samples-combo-with-webforms) which shows how to combine ASP.NET Web Forms and DotVVM in one project.

Basically you need to install `DotVVM.Owin` and `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` packages in the project, add the OWIN Startup class where you register DotVVM middleware, and add the project type GUID in the `.csproj` file to make the Visual Studio extension for DotVVM work.